# Issue in *ngFor in Angular 9,when I'm trying to use it in anchor tag it is showing that "No Directive is matched on attribute ngFor"

Tags: angular, angular-directive

```
<a *ngFor="let recipe for recipes" href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
  <div class="pull left">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      <span class="pull-right">
          <img src="" alt="{{recipe.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px"/>
      </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

I am not able to use ngFor directive here, due to this message

Comment: Did you import AngularCommon module?

Comment: Yes, I have, but it is being considered as an unused import by the IDE, I 'm using WebStorm

Comment: You need to import it in the `imports` property of the NgModule annotation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

typo error :

instead of using `let recipe for recipes` you should use like  :

```
<a *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
```